# Batch file, repeating command?

Tags: batch-file

I'm writing a batch file that makes animated webp

```
@echo off
set OPTION=+100
webpmux.exe -frame 1.webp %OPTION% -frame 2.webp %OPTION% -frame 3.webp %OPTION% -frame 4.webp %OPTION% ......... -frame n.webp %OPTION% -o animated.webp
echo done
pause
```

In "........." part, I want to command '-frame 5.webp %OPTION%' ~ '-frame n-1.webp %OPTION%'

How can I repeat that -frame n.webp %OPTION%' command?

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET n=30
SET "argument="
FOR /L %%r IN (1,1,%n%) DO SET "argument=!argument!-frame %%r.webp %%OPTION%% "
set OPTION=+100
ECHO webpmux.exe %argument%-o animated.webp
echo done

GOTO :EOF
```

should get the job done. You don't specify `n`, so I used `30`. The `webpmux` command is merely `echo`ed. You'd need to change `ECHO webpmux.exe` to `webpmux.exe` to activate it.

Comment: `set OPTION=+100` should be above the `for` loop and change `%%OPTION%%` to `%OPTION%` as the option should be used in the command line as I understand it.  The way it is currently the `+100` is not used in the echo command.